# Simplest way to store a quantum superposition temporarily

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

My understanding of the Schroedinger's Cat experiment is that, while it's an amusing thought experiment, the cat would not actually be in a superposition of states because it's just too massive an object. (Not to mention, it would be touching the box, so its movements would affect the larger world, etc.)

I'm wondering if there would be some real way to do something equivalent with inexpensive components. For example, suppose you had a bit of uranium and and a Geiger counter in a box, hooked up to a Raspberry Pi. If the Geiger counter registers something within a certain time frame, that information gets stored in a bit of the memory of the Pi.

Then, you can open the box, plug the Pi into another device, and query the bit state.

In this scenario, there is much less mass involved. As far as I can tell, nothing but electrons were influenced until the box was opened. Not a lot of mass.

The purpose of this scenario would be that someone could hold the box in their hands, and have the clear knowledge of exactly what quantum superposition we're talking about. For a time, while the box is in your hands, that bit would be both flipped and not flipped. If this idea is valid at all! :)

If it isn't valid, I'm wondering if anyone can think of an equivalently cheap, easy way of getting the same effect... there would be a period where you could hold a device in your hands that contains a quantum superposition where anyone could understand what it is that's in a state of superposition, and the device could be checked to make the superposition resolve and find what state it resolves to.

Comment: "It would be both flipped and not flipped"??!?!?

Comment: is the Raspberry Pi + the detector a proper quantum device in this context  ? not, it reads the outcome and ends this superposition. What happens next is another experiment on the knowledge, but not involving QM. There are quantum memories of another kind. In their context, your question takes some sense. Search for teleportation and focalize on the memory function ...

Comment: What is the point of holding in your hand some hidden and inaccessible superposed state, the nature of which you will never experience directly in any way? Just take any box and imagine that its content is an amazingly weird quantum state; you will get the same psychological results.

Comment: The "measurement" in case of the decay in Schroedinger's cat is made in femtoseconds by the vaccuum state surrounding the nucleus. Schroedinger didn't understand that in 1935 and most people don't seem to understand it today, either. Every attempt to look beyond the real of nuclear physics and quantum field theory is, in this case, a mental mouse trap.

Comment: After some search, it appears that you cannot build a paradox like that, even with a qbits storage device. In fact, you must memorize the "state(s) of the small bit of uranium" and not the event when it occurs. It's a little complicated for a simple thought experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know any simple ways to store a qubit, which is what you're asking for. Definitely nothing you could hold in your hand, unless you like hefting dilution refrigerators.

Actually, it's worse than that. We don't have any good *complicated* ways to store a qubit either. [Not for very long](http://www.livescience.com/41217-long-quantum-bit-achieved.html), anyways. Especially if you want to be able to apply operations to the qubit. Then it's impressive to keep one coherent for even a second.